# Losing reference when ordering sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am an excel beginner, so it may be difficult for me to use the exact terminology, therefore I will try to keep it simple in my description. 
Situation:

I have a worksheet `ingredients` with a list of kitchen ingredients with two columns: `name` and `price`. In another worksheet `recipes` I have the dishes recipes where I list the ingredient, the quantity and the price (giving reference the price in `ingredient` worksheet).

The issue is that if I add/delete/order in the `ingredients` list, I loose all the price references in the `recipes` worksheet (the reference formula still there but return a different price).

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `VLOOKUP` for the references. This references will be dependent on a criteria and not only on the position in the table.

Example:

Sheet `ingredients`:

[image]

Sheet `recipes`:

[image]

Formula in `recipes!C2` downwards:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,ingredients!A:B,2,FALSE)
```